# An allocation problem of people into groups getting them to meet as little as possible

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, theory, np

I have been trying to solve this for quite a while without success.
I have not found (I searched though) theory that could help me on wikipedia.

Here is the problem.

I have a group of n players (more than 7)
I have a game (diplomacy for those who know !) that requires 7 players, one for these roles : E,F,G,I,A,R and T (countries in fact)

I want to set up a tournament (many games).

There will be n games.

(*) Every player gets into 7 different games, with different role each time

(**) Every game gets 7 different players

=> That is very easy to do.

However, when things get tough, is when you want to limit interactions between players.
What I want is any player to interact (interact = play in same game) at *most* with one other player.
(In other words, I want to prevent players from making such deals : "I help you in game A, you help me in game B")

So:

Question 1 : For which n is this possible ? (obviously at least 50)

Question 2 : When it is possible, how do you do it ?

Question 3 : What is the algo to minimize these interactions when it is not possible ?

For the record, I did implement a try-and-error program in python (using recursion), working quite well, but I never can get maximum intearctions between players limited to 1 (endless calculations)

thanks for any help !

PS This is no homework, it is for actually designing game tournaments  :-)

Comment: I think I am running into this problem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem

Comment: This is a hard problem. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69325/social-golfer-problem-quintets

Comment: If you can cap the tournament size, I know there's a solution with n = 49 based on two mutually orthogonal 7x7 Latin squares.

Comment: "What I want is any player to interact (interact = play in same game) at _most_ with one other player." I don't quite get this one. Do you rather mean that you want any two players to meet each other at most in one game?

Comment: "Question 1 : For which n is this possible ? (obviously at least 50)"  Are you thinking 7x7 + 1?  If I understand right, for any player, each round there would need to be 6 new other players that the player had never played with before.  With 7 rounds, that is 6*7+1 for the original player.  So, if everyone could play with everyone else once, the hypothetical lower bound would be 43.  But please say more about how you would handle numbers of players that are not a multiple of 7?  Are multiples of 7 required?  Would some play a board with less than 7 players?  Would some not play every round?

Comment: David : I do not tink there is any solution with 49 players. I may be wrong. Can you show the solution ? Besides I need an answer for any number of players.

Comment: Astrid : yes you understood right

Comment: Eric : number of players do not divide 7. You make as many games as players. Players all go in 7 games. Games all take 7 players. And, there is one more constraint compared to the school girl problem : in a game, there are 7 roles, a player must not havs same role in two different games

Comment: @David : in your example 30 meets 37 more than once. In every game !

Comment: @Jeremie screwed that up slightly. Fixed, I think: `[[[((i+k)%7)*7 + (i*k+j)%7 for k in range(7)] for j in range(7)] for i in range(7)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I did some doodling and I think; If I understand you correctly, that you can do the following:

1. 28 people to do the 7 roles/7 games meeting other players only once.
2. If the position of a person in the following games is allocated to distinct roles then no person plays the same role in the games they play.

**Python**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71143133/an-allocation-problem-of-people-into-groups-getting-them-to-meet-as-little-as-po

Created on Sat Feb 19 21:15:02 2022

@author: paddy3118

By hand to get the algo:
    0 roles, 0 people for 0 interactions
    1 role, 1 person
    2 roles, 3 people: p0+p1, p1+p2
    3 roles,   012, 134, 235 = 6 people
    4 roles,   0123, 1456, 2478, 3579 = 10 people
"""

from itertools import count


def new_person():
    yield from count()

def people_allocation(roles: int=4):
    games, new_p = [], count()
    for i in range(roles):
        game = []
        games.append(game)
        for j in range(i):
            game.append(games[j][i])
        for _ in range(i, roles):
            game.append(next(new_p))
    return games, next(new_p)

for roles in range(8):
    print(f"Roles = {roles}:")
    games, people = people_allocation(roles)
    print(f"  Takes {people} people in the following games")
    print('  ',
          ', '.join('+'.join(f"P{x}" for x in game) for game in games))
```

**Output**

```
Roles = 0:
  Takes 0 people in the following games
   
Roles = 1:
  Takes 1 people in the following games
   P0
Roles = 2:
  Takes 3 people in the following games
   P0+P1, P1+P2
Roles = 3:
  Takes 6 people in the following games
   P0+P1+P2, P1+P3+P4, P2+P4+P5
Roles = 4:
  Takes 10 people in the following games
   P0+P1+P2+P3, P1+P4+P5+P6, P2+P5+P7+P8, P3+P6+P8+P9
Roles = 5:
  Takes 15 people in the following games
   P0+P1+P2+P3+P4, P1+P5+P6+P7+P8, P2+P6+P9+P10+P11, P3+P7+P10+P12+P13, P4+P8+P11+P13+P14
Roles = 6:
  Takes 21 people in the following games
   P0+P1+P2+P3+P4+P5, P1+P6+P7+P8+P9+P10, P2+P7+P11+P12+P13+P14, P3+P8+P12+P15+P16+P17, P4+P9+P13+P16+P18+P19, P5+P10+P14+P17+P19+P20
Roles = 7:
  Takes 28 people in the following games
   P0+P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6, P1+P7+P8+P9+P10+P11+P12, P2+P8+P13+P14+P15+P16+P17, P3+P9+P14+P18+P19+P20+P21, P4+P10+P15+P19+P22+P23+P24, P5+P11+P16+P20+P23+P25+P26, P6+P12+P17+P21+P24+P26+P27
```

Comment: Paddy : thanks, but you do not get  a "good" solution. I see P0 is only in one game. P0 must be in 7 games in 7 different positions. Sorry !

Comment: That is because of the restriction that no player can be in a game with another player - no matter the role, **more than once**.
In the 7 roles case, for example; P0 plays with P1-P6 once. P4 plays with P0-P6 and P10-P24 also, once only.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that n ≥ 78 or so, the following simple hill climbing algorithm with periodic restarts will return a solution.

The algorithmic idea is to initialize games where each player plays each role exactly once, then drive the number of conflicts to zero (where a conflict is a player playing two roles in a single game, or two players meeting each other more than once) by choosing two random games and a random role and swapping the players involved. We restart every 10<sup>7</sup> steps because that seems to work well in practice.

Doubtless we could do a little better with constraint programming.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

constexpr int r = 7;

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  if (n <= r * (r - 1)) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_game(0, n - 1);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_role(0, r - 1);
  std::random_device device;
  std::default_random_engine engine(device());
  while (true) {
    std::vector<std::array<int, r>> games(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
        games[i][j] = (i + j) % n;
      }
    }
    int badness = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> pair_counts(n, std::vector<int>(n, 0));
    auto count = [&badness, &games, &pair_counts](int i, int j, int increment) {
      for (int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
        if (k == j) continue;
        auto [a, b] = std::minmax(games[i][j], games[i][k]);
        badness -= pair_counts[a][b] > (a != b ? 2 : 0);
        pair_counts[a][b] += increment;
        badness += pair_counts[a][b] > (a != b ? 2 : 0);
      }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
        count(i, j, 1);
      }
    }
    for (long t = 0; t < 10000000; t++) {
      int i1;
      int i2;
      do {
        i1 = uniform_game(engine);
        i2 = uniform_game(engine);
      } while (i1 == i2);
      int j = uniform_role(engine);
      auto swap_players = [&]() {
        count(i2, j, -2);
        count(i1, j, -2);
        std::swap(games[i1][j], games[i2][j]);
        count(i1, j, 2);
        count(i2, j, 2);
      };
      int old_badness = badness;
      swap_players();
      if (old_badness < badness) {
        swap_players();
      } else if (badness < old_badness) {
        std::cerr << badness << '\n';
      }
      if (badness <= 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            if (j) std::cout << ' ';
            std::cout << games[i][j];
          }
          std::cout << '\n';
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
21 38 61 75 77 2 22
70 31 75 7 15 59 69
28 52 29 73 59 23 40
61 45 16 65 35 15 55
12 72 44 45 46 14 10
57 1 3 38 11 6 49
20 6 7 26 0 74 18
54 73 67 58 6 55 75
73 77 63 36 3 0 45
37 57 55 28 34 43 7
17 46 36 66 16 7 48
74 9 24 22 17 73 15
36 50 4 69 28 65 6
59 62 12 32 24 20 51
38 8 59 17 10 19 39
6 53 21 70 13 71 56
55 33 49 59 5 27 36
15 71 33 54 43 18 29
60 36 8 40 71 51 67
19 49 9 34 45 53 60
41 26 73 21 72 35 19
14 64 42 15 57 63 62
44 11 23 27 9 16 21
2 7 68 9 63 52 54
35 18 2 3 60 64 17
29 17 50 41 31 61 57
47 10 32 25 75 28 35
30 48 64 6 32 39 44
46 22 71 35 20 31 11
43 76 41 11 47 60 14
56 2 1 33 74 10 37
51 41 39 0 33 70 34
32 5 18 31 23 76 68
65 43 53 8 27 46 73
63 44 26 5 70 24 28
62 75 66 71 44 3 41
16 69 54 13 22 41 5
58 19 52 57 36 22 70
42 25 22 44 55 56 76
4 30 35 51 76 13 9
72 13 17 62 40 77 43
53 16 10 68 50 58 64
64 47 70 55 38 40 20
50 59 14 48 1 9 71
40 63 19 76 69 1 12
24 35 69 56 68 57 27
67 34 15 72 56 66 32
68 3 46 37 25 21 59
77 54 47 19 4 44 31
76 67 38 46 52 50 33
25 15 77 1 51 26 23
3 61 40 4 53 5 74
45 51 74 29 48 68 47
75 0 57 23 30 8 72
13 27 28 14 19 67 2
9 20 72 42 65 33 3
49 58 48 20 41 37 77
22 12 37 67 39 47 53
26 42 11 61 37 36 13
1 60 5 39 29 75 46
48 40 65 10 54 34 26
23 66 60 50 42 54 24
8 74 13 63 49 32 50
27 29 58 12 7 38 42
7 4 45 24 64 25 8
71 24 30 47 2 49 16
31 28 56 60 12 48 0
10 23 62 49 67 69 61
34 21 31 30 58 62 1
66 70 27 18 61 30 25
0 37 76 64 66 29 65
69 39 43 2 26 45 58
39 65 25 74 62 11 52
5 56 20 52 14 17 30
33 68 6 77 8 12 66
11 55 51 53 18 72 63
52 32 0 43 21 42 4
18 14 34 16 73 4 38
```

Comment: David : your approach seems promising. Can you please be kind enought to give complete description of you hill climbing parameters ? I have in the past implemented an hill climbing for solving zodiac ciphers so the concept is quite familiar to me. What is tyour evaluation function ? What is your transition ? When do you restart ? What are your annealing parameters ? etc...

Comment: @Jeremie added some details, simplified the code.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I think I solved this problem.
I explain it here to help any other person facing such a problem.

I used two "classical" algorithms.

1. *try-and-error* to get a first configuration of low quality, with iterations that tries first those players with fewest intearctions and which are already in more games
2. *hill-climibing* to improve quality of configuration (making swaps between a conflicting and not conflicting player, or two conflicting players if all players are conflicting) and selecting randomly, keeping the result of swap only if it increases quality - quality is worst number of conflicts (2 usually) and number of occurences)

I reach the following conclusion :

- always a solution above 100
- never a solution below 90

Thanks for all support you provided !